# Listview onitemclicklistener not working for Check box?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a list view whose element is as below containing one checkbox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="64dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewVoucherIcon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewVoucherText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkboxVoucherClick"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:text="sas"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewVoucherIcon" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkboxVoucherClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/seperator" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my onitem click listener

```
 lvVoucher.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)  {
           CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkboxVoucherClick);
            if(cb.isChecked())
            {
                Log.e("check","true");
            }else{
                Log.e("check","false");
            }
        }
    });
```

But it does not returns anything.

Comment: DO you want different action for CheckBox and other widgets ? Or only you want click action for checkBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the focus to the checkbox in layout then it will work.

like this:

```
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

or else you have to write that listener in adapter itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this worked for me;

Set these following properties for your checkbox:

```
      android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new line to your xml parent layout -

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

So your updated view will be like below -

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

it will sure work for you.

Answer (score 0):

do work in `getView`

```
 holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
 public void onClick(View v) {  
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;  
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
   "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
   " is " + cb.isChecked(), 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }  
});
```